# How to create a custom event with custom parameters in GA4 - google analytics 4

Tags: reactjs, events, google-analytics-4

I am trying to create a GA4 (google analytics) custom event with custom params, like this:

`{  "event_name": "game_over", "action": "message shown",  "label": {the current url},  "data": {some JSON object data}  }`

Which I will send from my react website to the already setup google analytics project.

**What I have tried:**

I read the docs of GA4 and has found it unhelpful and in the google searches nothing came but 'Universal Analytics' and no GA4 articles.
Except for 1, the following: [custome event GA4](https://www.delasign.com/blog/custom-ga-event-reactjs-gatsbyjs/), which helped me to create a custom event but not custom params as well.

I am still searching for an answer, but if someone will be able to help it would be great!

(N*ote for 1500 or higher stack overflow members*: Please add the GA4 (or ga4) tag to the question as I can't do it because I don't have permit to do so, and also erase this note after [I think it is needed])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution.

You need to do as written in the following article: [custome event GA4](https://www.delasign.com/blog/custom-ga-event-reactjs-gatsbyjs/)

But in **step 2** change the 'TrackGoogleAnalyticsEvent' method to be as follow:

```
const TrackGoogleAnalyticsEvent = (
    category,
    event_name,
    label,
    data
) => {
    console.log("GA event:", category, ":", event_name, ":", label);

    let event_params = {
        category,
        label,
        ...data
    };
    // Send GA4 Event
    ReactGA4.event(event_name, event_params);
};
```

And in the client side you need to have the following code:

```
TrackGoogleAnalyticsEvent(
                "game_over",
                "message shown",
                window.location.pathname + window.location.search,
                { id: 1234, username: "john" }
            );
```

Note: You can enter as many parameters you like in the JSON object.

For more information, a link to the 'react-ga4' package: [react-ga4 docs](https://github.com/codler/react-ga4)