# creating a custom event with custom parameters in GA4 using react js

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

[This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75972474/how-to-create-a-custom-event-with-custom-parameters-in-ga4-google-analytics-4), which helped me to create a custom event with custom params as well in react. I can able to see those parameters in GA realtime and events reports as well. But I had a question create a custom event with custom param will be the same when using Custom dimensions and Custom metrices in GA4.
if not, then what do I integrate Custom dimensions and Custom metrices in my react application(using react-ga4)

Have Integration GA4 with React and sending custom events and custom params as well.
my current code:

```
const trackGoogleAnalyticsEvent = (category: string, event_name: string, data?: object, label?: string) => {
    const userData = {
      user_name: loginDetail?.name,
      role: loginDetail?.idTokenClaims?.role,
      supplier_consumer_mapped: userAccessMapping?.map(({ SupplierName }) => SupplierName)?.join(', '),
      ...data,
    }
    const event_params = {
      category,
      label,
      ...userData,
    }
    // Send GA4 Event
    console.log({ event_name, event_params })
    ReactGA4.event(event_name, event_params)
  }
```